# How can I get the return value from exec without capturing the output?

Tags: php, exec

When calling `exec()`, I want to capture the return value of the call, but I'm not interested in the output itself. `exec()` provides two optional parameters, passed by reference, which will be populated by the output and return value respectively.

So I could do this, and just ignore `$output`:

```
exec($command, $output, $return_value);
```

But what if there's a lot of output? I don't want to run out of memory as `$output` fills up.

I thought maybe I could do this, but obviously it's not valid to pass a literal by reference, which I soon found out:

```
exec($command, null, $return_value);
```

So now I'm wondering, is there a way around this?

I *could* adjust the value of `$command` to redirect output to `/dev/null` at the shell level, which solves the memory usage issue, but it's not a good solution if I can't predict the starting value of `$command`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [system ( string $command [, int &$return_var ] )](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php).  It writes the return status to the second argument and only returns the last line of output that you need not assign if you don't need it:

```
system($command, $return_value);
```